# 4-way flood fill function without passing starting color

Tags: c++, recursion, flood-fill

I need to write a recursive flood fill function which prototype looks like this:

```
bool fill(PixMap& image,Pixel fillColour,int x, int y)
```

image is the "image" part of which will be flood filled, fillColour is the color that gonna be used to fill the certain area of a picture. x and y ary coordinates of first pixel that will be filled. Problem is that algorithms that I found online include also oldColor variable, or the original color that starting pixel has. And if pixel that gonna be filled with the color is not the same color as the original one than recursion stops.

```
    void floodFill4(int x, int y, int newColor, int oldColor) 
{ 
    if(x >= 0 && x < w && y >= 0 && y < h && screenBuffer[x][y] == oldColor && screenBuffer[x][y] != newColor) 
    { 
        screenBuffer[x][y] = newColor; //set color before starting recursion

        floodFill4(x + 1, y,     newColor, oldColor);
        floodFill4(x - 1, y,     newColor, oldColor);
        floodFill4(x,     y + 1, newColor, oldColor);
        floodFill4(x,     y - 1, newColor, oldColor);
    }     
}
```

However, in my prototype there is no such variable and I does not allowed to change it. How do I do the recursion flood fill that does not flood all of the image?

Comment: you need to pass in old color.  otherwise, how does it know what to fill?  newColor = what to fill with.  oldColor = what to fill.

Comment: how about you read `screenBuffer[x][y]` fist, and then call the other version

Comment: Or you need to pass a border color; a color of the pixel which bounds the fill area.  Another method is to pass the enclosing curve or polygon as the boundary for the fill.

Comment: By the way, you may want to research how Graphics Processor Units perform their flood fills and their API.  Compatibility with the GPU's API will give you more portability.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, if you do any of those things, it's not flood fill anymore :p  It's polygon fill and maybe boundary fill.

Comment: Make a function which looks at the starting colour, then calls your existing function?

Comment: BTW, the "4 way" algorithm is probably most impractical flood fill algorithm.

Comment: I would guess they are not doing it recursively, but perhaps with some internal stacks. One way you could do this recursively is to have global statics so that you can detect the first time you call the function and read the color and latch it, then every other call you refer to the latched value as your fill color.

Comment: What's wrong with `oldColor = image[x,y]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about what the function prototype says:

Fill image at x/y with `fillColor`.

It does not say:

Fill image at x/y with `fillColor` when there is `oldColor`, else do nothing.

The latter its your `floodfill4` prototype. When `floodfill4` is called, it's not certain if a fill will occur, because it first has to check.

On the other hand, your target prototype will *always* fill -- that's why it doesn't need `oldColor`.

Long story short: instead of testing once for old color, do this instead:

```
if pixel at x/y is fillColor:
    return
save oldColor at x/y
replace pixel at x/y with fillColor

for all neighboring pixels:
    if pixel at neighbor is oldColor:
        recursive call
```